# How can I make the code pause 5 seconds after every email sent

Tags: python, email, smtplib

I need the code to sleep every time it sends an email by 5 seconds, when I use `sleep(5)` it just sends all the emails and then pauses.

The code:

```
import pandas as pd
import smtplib
from time import sleep

SenderAddress='<xxxx@gmail.com>'

e = pd.read_excel("C:xxx/Email.xlsx")
sleep(5)
emails = e['Emails'].values
server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com:587")
server.starttls()
server.login('xxx@gmail.com', 'xxxxx')

msg = 'Testing the code'

subject = "Congratulations"
body = "Subject: {}\n\n{}".format(subject,msg)
for email in emails:
  server.sendmail(SenderAddress, email, body)
server.quit()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try transferring the sleep method to the body of the loop. Like this

```
import pandas as pd
import smtplib
from time import sleep

SenderAddress='<xxxx@gmail.com>'

e = pd.read_excel("C:xxx/Email.xlsx")
emails = e['Emails'].values
server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com:587")
server.starttls()
server.login('xxx@gmail.com', 'xxxxx')

msg = 'Testing the code'

subject = "Congratulations"
body = "Subject: {}\n\n{}".format(subject,msg)
for email in emails:
  server.sendmail(SenderAddress, email, body)
  sleep(5)
server.quit()
```

Answer (score 1):

Just put `sleep(5)` inside of your for loop:

```
for email in emails:
    server.sendmail(SenderAddress, email, body)
    sleep(5)
```

So that everytime you call `server.sendmail` you then wait 5 seconds

Comment: Yeah, it worked perfectly, thank you, it was easy but I'm still a noob :p